# String and substring and how many times substring present in main string

Tags: java, string, substring

I have written code by help of some solutions in Google. Can you please help me on what the while loop does in detail?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoStringsWordRepeat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Sentence: ");
        String sentence = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter word: ");
        String word = s.nextLine();
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (lastIndex != -1) {
            lastIndex = sentence.indexOf(word, lastIndex);
            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                count++;
                lastIndex += word.length();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Explain me the code in while loop `.indexOf();`.

Comment: indexOf() finds the first occurrence of the `word` in  `sentence`, starting the search at position `lastIndex` as per the variables used in the code block of urs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sentence.indexOf(word,lastIndex);` Returns the index of string`word`, starting from the specified index `lastIndex`. otherwise will return `-1`

It will search for the `word`in the given `sentence` starting from given `lastIndex`

Added the comments in the code .

```
// While we are getting the word in the sentence
// i.e while it is not returning -1
while(lastIndex != -1) {
    // Will get the last index of the searched word
    lastIndex = sentence.indexOf(word, lastIndex);

    // Will check whether word found or not 
    if(lastIndex != -1) {
        // If found will increment the word count
        count++;
        // Increment the lastIndex by the word lenght
        lastIndex += word.length();
    }
}

// Print the count
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` returns the offset of the first occurance of the given substring in the search-string or `-1` if it can't find the respective string.

With the alternative syntax it is possible to start the search at a given offset so it will only find matches after that particular start-offset.

If the `word` has been found then it will do another iteration but starts the serach right at the end of the last found occurance of `word`